# Minor change to array format to use with flot charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, flot

The first part of my script looks like this:

```
$.getJSON('age_get.php', function(data) {
  var ticks1=[]
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {                  
  ticks1.push("["+val.index+",'"+val.value+"']");
            });
var ticks6 =[(ticks1.join())]
```

This outputs (for ticks6) something like this:

```
["[90,'18-24'],[91,'25-29'],[92,'30-34'],[93,'35-39'…'60-64'],[99,'65-69'],[100,'70-74'],[101,'75-99']"]
```

I'm trying to use this array in flot charts and it's almost perfect.

The code in the plot portion of my script to draw the y axis looks like this:

```
yaxis: {
    ticks:ticks6,
    autoscaleMargin: 0.02
    },
```

The format that it is expecting is:

```
[[90,'18-24'],[91,'25-29'],[92,'30-34'],[93,'35-39'…'60-64'],[99,'65-69'],[100,'70-74'],[101,'75-99']]
```

It's ALMOST exactly what I have, but I need the leading and trailing pair of double quotes removed. I can't figure out how to do this though.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with flot, but from what you are saying, the expected format seems to be a multidimensional array, or an array of arrays, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra step that is creating a big string. Thus `ticks6` is really an array with one element that is a big string that looks like an array.

The length of array `ticks6` as shown in question is 1.

All you need to do is push each new 2 element array straight into the array that will be used for flot data

```
var ticks6 = []; /* array to pass to flot*/
$.getJSON('age_get.php', function (data) {    
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
       /* no quotes wrapping array braces, push 2 element array into main array */
        ticks6.push([val.index, "'" + val.value + "'"]);
    });    
});
```

it might be easier to visualize the array push this way:

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
     /* create 2 element array */
     var chartPointArray = [val.index, "'" + val.value + "'"];
     /* push 2 element array to main array */
     ticks6.push( chartPointArray  );
});
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Your fixed worked great. Thanks for the additional detail too.